# I have a problem when trying to run my Android application with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I linked my Android Studio project with Firebase, but when I try to run the app, I get a build error.

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library 
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: You have to update minSdkVersion to 16 in your app build Gradle file in the default config block.

Comment: Update gradle file same as your app.gradle file.. both file needs to be on same sdk and target version. just need to update minSdkVersion in app level gradle file 14 to 16

Answer (score 2):

Go to your build.gradle(module : app)
and change minSdkVersion to 16

Answer (score 1):

set your minSdkVersion larger than 16.